# HDD "unknown", "not initialized", no capacity, no nothing. But physically working and showing up in the device manager

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, external-hard-drive, hardware-failure, disk-image

It's a 
[WD hard disk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEHtR.jpg).

I'm using its original PCB and the disk turns on, is physically running, and the
[WD software diagnostic shows "PASS"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/toBKz.png).

It appears in 
[the device manager, but in the disk management is shows as "unknown" "not initialized"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxJGx.png).

I tried to "rebuild MBR" and 
["partition recovery"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0JI0.png) but nothing worked...

[Info about the disk (R-studio)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KC4ps.png)

For some time, this disk had been having some issues: sometimes, I tried to open it on Windows and it took a while and only then it showed the folders inside; sometimes, the HDD didn't even appear, and then often I just restarted the computer and then it would appear. But now it's this.

What could I do to recover the data from this disk?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You should create an image of the hard disk, then recover data from the image. This software is good for your case: Easy Recovery https://www.ontrack.com/products/data-recovery-software/

Comment: It didn't find anything: https://i.imgur.com/UNbf2Pu.png